# Hold output of batch command until a specific time

Tags: batch-file, cmd, openhardwaremonitor

I am making a batch script to send numbers through the serial port to an Arduino with 1 second delays.

```
@echo off
mode COM3: baud=9600 data=8 >nul
for /l %%n in () do (
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`wmic /namespace:\\root\openhardwaremonitor path sensor where "Identifier='/intelcpu/0/temperature/0'" get value^|findstr [0-9]`) do <nul set /p ="%%a">COM3
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`wmic /namespace:\\root\openhardwaremonitor path sensor where "Identifier='/nvidiagpu/0/temperature/0'" get value^|findstr [0-9]`) do <nul set /p ="%%a">COM3
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
)
```

It mainly works but it gets out of sync when running intensive tasks like gaming because the wmic commands are taking longer. I tried to squeeze every bit of performance by using the `<nul set /p` commands and setting to a higher priority but it didn't work. I was looking into commands like `AT` where it schedules a command at a time but it seems that it just runs the command then which is not what I want.

---

**Is there a way to use a command similar to timeout but it processes the command during the alloted time, so it can immidiately output when the time is over?**

Comment: I would suggest that running `WMIC`, `FINDSTR` and `TIMEOUT` every second is in itself an intensive task!

Comment: I don't know `wmic` but you are starting 6 processes here. Can you get both numbers by calling `wmic` just once with different parameters maybe? Or can you start 2 `wmics` in the background and then wait for both with timeout? Or can you use `python` or another language that just makes library calls to `wmic` rather than starting processes?

Comment: pretty sure calling both `wmic`'s will bring up way too much data than I need, and possibly slow it down more. I'm changing the delay from 1 second to 3 seconds to see if that will help, but i'll look in to calling one wmic.

Comment: @Compo it only shows less than 1% cpu usage at a point in time, even including the separate processes for the commands

Comment: WMIC has an `/EVERY` switch that you could try. `/EVERY:<interval> [/REPEAT:<repeat count>] - Returns value every (X interval) seconds, If /REPEAT specified the command is executed <repeat count> times`.

Comment: `<nul set /p` is much slower than `echo`. I'm not suggesting that `set /p` is the culprit. it is nothing compare to `find` and specially `wmic` but since you were after every bit of performance you should know that theoretically you've made it worse but practically it doesn't make a difference for your case.

Comment: I would suggest that you run `wmic` in a separate thread with longer intervals than the main thread say every 2 seconds and redirect its output to a file, then in the main thread with 1 second interval, first try to read `wmic's` output file, if the file was locked it means `wmic` has not yet finished so you can immediately resend the previous value to feed your Arduino at expected intervals then try to read the file send the new value at the next interval.